# What is the relative version of a reduced scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes

I have often heard it said that it is important to think of properties of a scheme $X$ as really a special case of a property of morphisms applied to the morphism $X\to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Z$.

Some examples of this pattern are being affine, separated, quasi-compact, quasi-separated and so on.

Is there a similar relative version of the notion of a scheme being reduced (or integral or irreducible)? I have searched a little bit and there seems to be no mention of such things anywhere.

If it is true that we don't have a useful notion of such things, is there any reason why? This is of course a little vague and I am not really sure what answer would satisfy me.

Edit: Specifically for reduced versions of morphisms, I think they should have the following properties:

1. They should be affine.
2. They should be closed under base change(pullback/fiber products) and composition.
3. (More speculative) The property should be expressible purely as a property about the induced morphisms on the stalks.

Comment: I mean, the obvious guess as to what such a notion might mean is that the fibers of the map $f:X\to Y$ are blah.

Comment: I guess the question is, what does blah stand for? I have added a few properties I think such morphisms should have too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reduced morphisms are defined in EGA IV.6.8.1. Irreducible morphisms are defined in EGA IV.4.5.5.

Comment: Everything really is in EGA uh...I will accept this answer after looking at the relevant sections once, thank you.

Comment: I tried reading it but my french is sorely lacking. Could you perhaps summarize the relevant sections(I am only really interested in reduced).

Comment: Dear Asvin, I am afraid that at the moment I do not have the time to write you an account of these things. But if you are going to do algebraic geometry you have to be able to read French (well, mathematical French) anyway. It is not as hard as it may seem at first, and it is certainly worth some effort.